# Update mongo document based on time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, scheduled-tasks

Lets say for example I'm making a game lobby and I want to have a "room" document which contains a open/closed state (boolean). I want to store in my database that this lobby is open for registration, up till 24 hours before game day. 24 hours before game day, I will mark the room document in the database as closed for registration, and will not display it to users in searches etc.

How can I update the field in mongo 24 hours before game day? I would also like the solution to be able to handle server restarts. I am connecting to mongodb through node.js and mongoose.

I am running the app on aws ebs, and the db will be on another service.

Comment: Just check if the time of registration is 24 hours in advance if now, don't allow the signup

Comment: @georoot I'm not sure about performance impact of a solution like this one, im not just just using the value for blocking signups, but also in queries to filter out ones that aren't open. Isn't having a state a better solution than always checking?

Comment: No, but if you want to get better performance, you can use memory cache to prevent calls to database to check the closing date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the difficulties in answering above is the need as you wrote: *"I would also like the solution to be able to handle server restarts."* Up until this point, you could use a cache to handle the state without having to deal with reading from the collection all the time. Also I am not clear if you are closing an entire collection based on a field parameter, or closing a field?? Not clear from the info you supplied.

However if you have installed Mongo correctly as a service on the server then already Mongo will restart when the server restarts. (No mention of what type of server you are on either.)

**Possibility #1:**
An NPM cache will disappear on server restart so you cannot rely on that. What you would need to do is either create a field or sep. collection, where simply put you would update once it is 24 hours before. You would have to run a function (cron job?) to close signups and place a field in a collection which would be set to Boolean (just a suggestion) like follows:

{"allowsignups": true/false possibilities}

I dont use Mongoose but it would handle the above in the schema. Native would also be handled correctly.

Unless you are using Redis, then a cache for holding it, due to your server restarts will not help.

**Possibility #2:**
Keep a simple JSON file on disk which contains the parameters sign up allowed or not. Have a routine that checks the time when someone is on, and if the JSON file has the `allowedsignups` set to `false` then dont allow it or show it. This is a simple `fs` in Node, and also will survive server restarts. It does not involve any read/write on a DB nor does it complicate your DB schema. And you can use the JSON file for multiple games and more parameters.

Your choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I just want to flip a boolean which tracks if its open for signups inside the room document when its 24 hours from game time. Im running my node js app on aws' elastic beanstalk. The mongo db will be hosted on another service. I was thinking of a file approach as well and just loading it into mem cache when the server boots up with any updates to values.  Thanks for the very detailed response.